# How would I link a `.lib` library from a different solution in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c, static-libraries, visual-studio-2019

Currently I am building a static library to read bitmap images in C. I am wanting for others to be able to link the library without access to the Visual Studio project it was created in. I can not figure out how to link my '.lib' file to another project, any ideas?

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2019. My '.lib' compiles successfully, when I reference it in another project (by adding a reference in the solution explorer) within the same solution everything works as intended.

However when I try to add it in a different solution by either setting the additional dependencies and library directories in the project configuration or adding the library to the resources folder the linker can not find the definitions for my header files in the library.

I have tried to set

```
Properties>Linker>General>Additional Library Directories
```

and

```
Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies
```

Both the properties I type in evaluate to the correct path but i still have no luck.

I expect my program to compile and run as it does when adding a reference to the library project within the same solution.

What i receive is:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol (any function symbol here)
```

Any help is appreciated, this is my first question so I am sorry if it is unclear :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link libraries through the #pragma directive. Try this.
`#pragma comment(lib,"libname")` At the top of your C/header file. Where libname is obviously the name of your library you are linking. The quotations need to stay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would i need to have my library at the root of my project directory? Or does the location not matter.

Comment: Yes put your lib in the directory with your header and c files. Since the path is relative. If you want to provide an absolute path to a directory you can do that too.

Comment: Ahhh, i was so stupid, my library was built for x64 and my target platform for the program was x86, changing this and using `#pragma comment works`!

Comment: Glad I could help.